# I have this strong feeling that im worshipping other than allah (shirk)

Tags: allah, shirk

Assalaam Alykum..in my past I never prayed I rarely read the Quran..but one day I started praying all 5 prayers on time.. I felt close to Allah to the point where I felt like I'm worshipping someone named Allah but isn't the true one...if I'm commiting shirk I want to repent but I don't know how because 1) the one I think I'm worshipping other than Allah is also named Allah so I don't know how to deal with this and how to tell the difference...2) I get a weird feeling when some one does dhikr or when I hear the Quran because something is telling me that "he's only your Lord how do they know about this" and " you are a kafir ..look at these Muslims there actually true Muslims not like you doing shirk" 3) I'm scared to do dhikr because I feel like I worship other than Allah.. I want to repent but I don't know how...please help..

Answer (score 0):

Repent to Allah their is only one Allah and the true god no other do not let shaitan fool you and make your life hard don’t be hard on yourself Just repent if you have done shirk before it’s too late and pray on time read the Quran and Allah will make it easy for you he is the one who always makes things better and Allah knows best.

Answer (score -1):

Don't look at anyone's Allah, don't think of anyone's Allah, study the Quran and study the qualities of Allah in Quran and if those qualities are present in your allah then you are worshipping the right one, please ask in comment if you have any question related to this

Answer (score -1):

The Prophet dealt with that problem himself.

One of the Companions went with Abu Bakr [RA] to the Prophet [PBUH], the Prophet said to Abu Bakr:

> Abu Bakr, indeed shirk spreads among you [i.e. Muslims] like the
> movement of ants.

Abu Bakr said:

> O Prophet, isn't shirk is worshiping idols beside Allah?

The Prophet repeated his statement again, and said:

> Should I tell you a supplication, if you said it; any shirk on you
> will fall?

He said:

> O Allah, I seek refuge in you that I associate with you by my own
> knowledge, **and I repent to you of what I have no knowledge.**

**Hadeeth:** https://sunnah.com/adab:716